# UBER Python API returns uber_rides.errors.ClientError

Tags: python, uber-api

I wrote a piece of code to get product information. I used the code provided in their [github](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk).

```
from uber_rides.session import Session
session = Session(server_token="key_given_here")

from uber_rides.client import UberRidesClient
client = UberRidesClient(session)
response = client.get_products(12.9242845,77.582953)
products = response.json.get('products')
print products
```

It returns the following error:

`uber_rides.errors.ClientError: The request contains bad syntax or cannot be filled due to a fault from the client sending the request.`

Why this happening. What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The code is working perfect. One character was missing in the `server_token` I provided.